# Passing data between dialog and panel

Tags: swing

I am new to swing, i have a box which gets opened from a frame. User has options to fill some data in the dialog, now this data needs to be passed to the frame and updated in table.

will firepropertychange work in this case?

Any help will be appreciated

thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest for you to either have a reference to the frame/table passed to your dialog. then on ok button click do the operations.

Or one more way create an action listener that will be called on ok button click in the frame, then in your custom dialog you will have appropriate methods to get the values from its field and you will add then to the table.

Good luck, Boro.

Comment: ok thanks, what are the possible ways of doing it without passing the reference?

Comment: Yes you could try using fire property change if you like. But you will need to get the fields somehow and you will probably only need this operation done on button click ok that is why I would suggest to go with a solution involving Action/ActionListener.   With the property change assign your own property name/type. Install property listener on this dialog, fire property change on click and you are done. But remember to filter out to use only your properties since there are few defaults being lunched.

Comment: I did notice, firepropertychange is makes my code lot more complex. Passing the reference is far more easier. So which is better approach?

Comment: From my own experience, I would strongly say that passing a reference is far 'better' solution, a more flexible one. For example, you can be general about what is the functionality of this dialog and reuse it, by passing to it a reference to it of a class implementing your interface. This way you have one dialog for displaying and running appropriate operations of a passed class. I have created for myself a dialog that install its own actions on a panel which I use as a view for a database entry when user is editing it.

Comment: Cool. Have fun and enjoy Java. :)